Plot_state_city question
qc = QuantumCircuit(2)
qc.h(0)
qc.x(1)
qc.cx(0,1)
state = Statevector(qc)
plot_state_city(state, alpha=0.6)

When this is graphed out, the following image is shown:

Why are all of these numbers specifically shown? I'm a beginner and don't understand the math behind it. Thanks!

The function plot_state_city plots two 3D bar graphs of the real and imaginary parts of the density matrix representation of the quantum state.
So, let's get the density matrix of the state in your question:
from qiskit.quantum_info import DensityMatrix

rho = DensityMatrix(state)
rho.draw('latex')

The result:
$$\begin{bmatrix} 0 & 0 & 0 & 0  \\ 0 & \frac{1}{2} & \frac{1}{2} & 0  \\ 0 & \frac{1}{2} & \frac{1}{2} & 0  \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 0  \\ \end{bmatrix}$$
You should be able to compare the matrix entries with the plot.
